# some branches in the output of "git branch -r" don't exist under .git/refs/remotes/origin directory

Tags: git

I use git branch -r to see the branches that tracked by local repo:

```
$git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/branch_a
  origin/branch_b
  origin/branch_c
```

but when I list the files under .git/refs/remotes/origin, I only get this

```
$ls -al
HEAD
master
branch_a
```

I use git fetch origin branch_b to get branch_b to local

```
$git fetch origin device_ping
From gitlab.xxx.com:groupa/projecta
 * branch            branch_a -> FETCH_HEAD
```

after this, I still cannot find branch_b under .git/refs/remotes/origin
so,

1. why I cannot find branch_b and branch_c?
2. where does git store the fetched content? could I see it use some commands?

Comment: They can be in `.git/packed_ref`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the references for your branches you have to inspect the directory `.git/refs/heads/` instead of `remotes/origin`. `remotes` is referring the remote(the url e.g.) and the `heads` directory is referring the particular branch heads.